# Delete dict elements by index list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, indexing, list-comprehension

I have a dict with different keys of the same length:

```
list_in_dict = list(range(0, 10))
test_dict = {"A" : list_in_dict , "B": list_in_dict , "C": list_in_dict}
```

Then I have a list with indices like this:

```
delete_index_list = [1,5,7]
```

I want to delete all elements in the keys, where the position corresponds to the index.

I tried this (but it totally fails):

```
for i in range(len(delete_index_list)):
    del(test_dict["A"][delete_index_list[i]])
    del(test_dict["B"][delete_index_list[i]])
    del(test_dict["C"][delete_index_list[i]])
```

Possibly I have to use list comprehension here? What would be the most compact way to achieve this result:

```
test_dict 
Out: 
{'A': [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9],
 'B': [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9],
 'C': [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]}
```

Comment: dict won't guarantee the order of keys. If you a strict relation - do the manual deletion or use mapping between keys and indices

Comment: The way you have your `test_dict` built, you only have to delete items from key `A`, since the other values are references to the same `list_in_dict`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **dict** and **list comprehension**:

```
{k:[elt for ind, elt in enumerate(v) if ind not in delete_index_list] for k,v in test_dict.items() }
```

Full code:

```
# Build data
list_in_dict = list(range(0, 10))
test_dict = {"A" : list_in_dict , "B": list_in_dict , "C": list_in_dict}

# Index to remve
delete_index_list = [1,5,7]

out = {k:[elt for ind, elt in enumerate(v) if ind not in delete_index_list] for k,v in test_dict.items() }
print(out)
# {'A': [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9],
#  'B': [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9],
#  'C': [0, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]}
```

Comment: Check the result if you change the list to `range(1, 10)`. You're removing the *values* 1, 5, and 7, not the *indices*. It's masked by the fact that the values and indices are identical in your test list.

Comment: you was faster than me,  I solve it in the same way. +1  for you and I deleted my answer :)

Comment: @glibdud Good point. This is fixed with an `enumeration`. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

The main issue with your approach is that once you remove index `1`, what was previously at index `5` is now actually at `4`. If the items in `delete_items_list` are sorted, you can get around that by starting at the end of the list and working your way back toward the beginning. (It's also unnecessary to mess with the indices of `delete_items_list`... that didn't cause a problem, but I've fixed it here to help with code readability.)

```
for i in reversed(delete_index_list):
    del(test_dict["A"][i])
    del(test_dict["B"][i])
    del(test_dict["C"][i])
```

You can be a little less repetitive by adding another for loop:

```
for k in test_dict:
    for i in reversed(delete_index_list):
        del(test_dict[k][i])
```

As suggested in another answer, if rebuilding the lists in `test_dict` is ok, that can be done with comprehensions. In order to properly remove indices and not values, you'll need to use `enumerate()`:

```
test_dict = {k : [val for i, val in enumerate(v) if i not in delete_index_list] for (k, v) in test_dict.items()}
```